# Customizing Error on JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, embed, jwplayer

I need to change the text that is output when the JWPlayer encounters an error and states "Video not found or access denied:filename.flv". I'm wondering if this is at all possible by passing through parameters to the embed object?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/player-development-and-customization/20811/sending-error-messages-to-jwplayer.

I don't believe it's possible to control the error message without digging in and editing the source.

- Andrew